# How to display birthday days of a user for next 5 years using mktime function in php

Tags: php

I'm using mktime function to display days of user inputted date of his birthday for next five years..?? But it is only displaying time in seconds only for one year 
I want successive date and days for next 5 years...

Comment: It's impossible to answer a question presented like this. Please share your code, a sample input, the output you get for this input and the output you'd want to get for it.

Comment: I don't know what is the code of it all i know is that this has to be done by mktime function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use DateTime to achieve it. Take a look at [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function if you want to add more tokens when formatting.

```
$birthdayOfThisYear = new DateTime('2016-11-25');
$numberOfYears = 5;

for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfYears; $i++) {

    echo $birthdayOfThisYear->format('l') . '<br />';

    $birthdayOfThisYear->modify("+1 year");
}
```

The output would be:

```
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
Monday
Wednesday
```

Comment: But sir we have to done this code by 'mktime' function..

Comment: why is that? it is a homework or what?

Comment: Yes, it is but i am not able to do this the time is displaying in seconds but the needed output is of the day of birthday of user for next 5 years..